# Uniform convergence and truncation error on a sector of the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a function that is analytic on the open unit disk, continuous and smooth on its boundary. Moreover, let $|f|^2$ be integrable on the entire unit circle and more specifically on the arc $\mathbb{T}_\alpha = \lbrace e^{i\theta} : -\alpha \leq \theta \leq +\alpha\rbrace$, where $0 < \alpha < \pi$. That is, $f \in H^2$. Specifically, I know an upper bound on
$$\int_{-\alpha}^{+\alpha} |f(e^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta \leq B.$$
Unfortunately, the value of the integral on the entire unit circle is not known.

I now expand $f$ on the open unit disk in terms of a set of polynomials $p_n(z)$:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n p_n(z).$$
The polynomials are orthonormal on $\mathbb{T}_\alpha$, such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |b_n|^2 \leq B.$$
This works nicely for a number of known toy models for $f$.
Let $\hat{f} = f - \sum b_n p_n$. I find for my toy models and for finite truncation of the series:

1. $|\hat{f}(z)|$ for $z$ in the sector $\mathbb{D}_\alpha = \lbrace r e^{i\theta} : 0 < r < 1, -\alpha < \theta < \alpha\rbrace$ is bounded by the value of $\hat{f}(z)$ on the arc $\mathbb{T}_\alpha$.
2. Even for $z$ on the two rays $\lbrace r e^{\pm i\alpha} : 0 \leq r < 1\rbrace$ I find that the maximum of $|\hat{f}|$ is only attained when $z$ as $r\to 1$.

I suspect that some clever combination of the maximum modulus principle could be used to show that my instinct is right and $\hat{f}$ (and therefore the truncation error) is bounded by the modulus on the arc only.

Maybe a friendly mathematician can help a poor physicist here? Can one prove my suspicion? I would already be ecstatic if one could prove that $|\hat{f}(z)|$ is bounded on $z \in (0, 1)$.

**Addendum**: I assume the whole exercise would be trivial if the polynomials were behaving well on the entire unit circle. This is not the case. As $n\to \infty$, $|p_n(-1)| = O(C^n)$ with $C > 1$.

Comment: Certainly (2) and the Maximum principle implies (1). but it isn't immediately clear to me that there is enough information here to guarantee that (2) must hold. Can you say any more about the polynomials $p_n$? For instance, do infinitely many of them have non-zero constant terms? Is $n$ the degree of $p_n$? Or is there at least some bound on how fast the degree of $p_n$ rises?

Comment: The polynomials are the orthonormal Szegő polynomials for the measure $d\mu(\theta) = \Theta(|\theta| - \alpha)$.
 - Yes, all of them have constant terms.
 - Yes, $n$ is the degree of $p_n$
 - The constant terms are decreasing (apparently exponentially) as the degree of the polynomials increases.